# Alinear 3 tablas horizontalmente responsivas

Tags: html, css, tabla-dinámica

No puedo alinearlas horizontalmente solo 2 de allas se dejan la de en medio no se quiere colocar en el centro para posisionarlas uso el float:left; float:rigth; pero para centrarla y que al momento de mover la pantalla sea responsica igual no se amontone eso funciona con 2 nadamas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo css:

```css
#tab2{
  float: left;
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 420px;
  margin: 26px;
  background:#1C2833;
}
 
#tab3{
  float: left;
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 425px;
  margin: 26px;
  background:#1C2833;                                                           
}

#tab4{
  float: right;
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 435px;
  margin: 26px;
  background:#1C2833; 
}
```

```html
<div id="tab2">
    <center>
        <h2 style="font-family: cursive;">Personal:</h2>
    </center>
    <table class="" id="tabla2">
        <tr class="fila2">
          <td>
            <select name="area" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Area de trabajo:</option>
              <option>Maquinas</option>
              <option>Encuadernacion</option>
              <option>Acabado</option>
            </select> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="nombre" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Nombre del trabajador:</option>
              <?php
                 $rows2=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
                 foreach ($rows2 as $row) { ?>
                  <option>
                    <?php echo $row['usuario'];?>
                  </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none;" class="eliminar"><i class="fa fa-times" width="35" height="35" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-der">
        <center>
          <button type="button" id="adicional2" class="boton_3">
            <img class="fa fa-plus" src="<?=URL ?>public/img/agregarusuario.png" width="35" height="35" />
            PERSONAL
          </button>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Haz tratado de usar flex-box en vez de float: left y right?

Comment: no como lo aria un ejemplo porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes implementar `flex-box` para lo que necesitas, te muestro un ejemplo:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#tab2{
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 420px;
  margin: 10px;
  background:#1C2833;
}
 
#tab3{
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 425px;
  margin: 10px;
  background:#1C2833;                                                           
}

#tab4{
  border:#CACFD2 20px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 435px;
  margin: 10px;
  background:#1C2833; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="tab2">
    <center>
        <h2 style="font-family: cursive;">Personal:</h2>
    </center>
    <table class="" id="tabla2">
        <tr class="fila2">
          <td>
            <select name="area" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Area de trabajo:</option>
              <option>Maquinas</option>
              <option>Encuadernacion</option>
              <option>Acabado</option>
            </select> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="nombre" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Nombre del trabajador:</option>
              <?php
                 $rows2=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
                 foreach ($rows2 as $row) { ?>
                  <option>
                    <?php echo $row['usuario'];?>
                  </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none;" class="eliminar"><i class="fa fa-times" width="35" height="35" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-der">
        <center>
          <button type="button" id="adicional2" class="boton_3">
            <img class="fa fa-plus" src="<?=URL ?>public/img/agregarusuario.png" width="35" height="35" />
            PERSONAL
          </button>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

<div id="tab3">
    <center>
        <h2 style="font-family: cursive;">Personal:</h2>
    </center>
    <table class="" id="tabla2">
        <tr class="fila2">
          <td>
            <select name="area" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Area de trabajo:</option>
              <option>Maquinas</option>
              <option>Encuadernacion</option>
              <option>Acabado</option>
            </select> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="nombre" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Nombre del trabajador:</option>
              <?php
                 $rows2=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
                 foreach ($rows2 as $row) { ?>
                  <option>
                    <?php echo $row['usuario'];?>
                  </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none;" class="eliminar"><i class="fa fa-times" width="35" height="35" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-der">
        <center>
          <button type="button" id="adicional2" class="boton_3">
            <img class="fa fa-plus" src="<?=URL ?>public/img/agregarusuario.png" width="35" height="35" />
            PERSONAL
          </button>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

<div id="tab4">
    <center>
        <h2 style="font-family: cursive;">Personal:</h2>
    </center>
    <table class="" id="tabla2">
        <tr class="fila2">
          <td>
            <select name="area" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Area de trabajo:</option>
              <option>Maquinas</option>
              <option>Encuadernacion</option>
              <option>Acabado</option>
            </select> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="nombre" class="select" id="letra2" required="">
              <option>Nombre del trabajador:</option>
              <?php
                 $rows2=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
                 foreach ($rows2 as $row) { ?>
                  <option>
                    <?php echo $row['usuario'];?>
                  </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none;" class="eliminar"><i class="fa fa-times" width="35" height="35" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-der">
        <center>
          <button type="button" id="adicional2" class="boton_3">
            <img class="fa fa-plus" src="<?=URL ?>public/img/agregarusuario.png" width="35" height="35" />
            PERSONAL
          </button>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
</div>
```

En este caso eliminas los `float: right - left` que usas en tus `tab`, y los posicionas a todos dentro de un contenedor padre, en este contenedor usas `flex-box` como te muestro en el ejemplo, puedes usar tanto `space-between` ó `space-around` para arreglar los contenedores como mejor te parezca, y si quieres los 3 en la misma linea ya tendrias que ir bajando con las propiedades `margin` ó `width` como mejor te parezca.

Comment: ya se pudo muchas gracias tu ejemplo me ayudo a entenderlo ya después movi a mi gusto y quedo como queria gracias